# Why does BeautifulSoup find keep returning elements with a class id other than what I'm passing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse an iframe containing a Korean news article and print out each individual body paragraph in the article. Because the Korean paragraph content lies in a p tag within its own td tag with a class id of "tlTD", I figured I could just loop through each td with that class name and print the p tag like so:

```py
link ="https://gloss.dliflc.edu/GlossHtml/GlossHTML.html?disableBrowserLockout=true&gloss=true&glossLoXmlFileName=/GlossHtml/templates/linksLO/glossLOs/kp_cul312.xml&glossMediaPathRoot=https://gloss.dliflc.edu/products/gloss/"
base_url = "https://oda.dliflc.edu"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
python_button = driver.find_element_by_id("gloss_link_source")
python_button.click() 

source_src= driver.find_element_by_id("glossIframe").get_attribute("src")
source_url = urljoin(base_url, source_src) 
driver.get(source_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml") 
for td in soup.find_all("td", class_="tlTD"):   
    print(soup.find("p").getText())
```

The problem is that, instead of printing the body paragraphs, the code repeatedly prints out only the article title which lies in in its own td with a class of "title tlTD". I tried using a lambda expression and a regex to make the class name more exclusive, but I kept getting the same result. Changing `soup.find("p")` to a `find_all` successfully made the code print what I wanted, but it also printed a bunch of English version content that I don't want.

I can understand why the article title content would be printed since it includes "tlTD" in the class name, but I'm baffled as to where the English content is coming from. When I inspected the page in google chrome it didn't include any English body paragraphs so why is BeautifulSoup scraping that? Can anyone help explain to me what's going on here and how I can get this code to just print the Korean body paragraph content?

Comment: Putting the URL in `link` into Firefox shows a security risk warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tlTD` class `td tag` inside iframe, you can access iframe data easily like:

xpath to locate iframe :

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='glossIframe']")))
```

Then switch_to the iframe:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Here's how to switch back to the default content (out of the ):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

[explicit-waits more details](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

EX:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
link = "https://gloss.dliflc.edu/GlossHtml/GlossHTML.html?disableBrowserLockout=true&gloss=true&glossLoXmlFileName=/GlossHtml/templates/linksLO/glossLOs/kp_cul312.xml&glossMediaPathRoot=https://gloss.dliflc.edu/products/gloss/"

driver.get(link)

source_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gloss_link_source")))
source_button.click()

#switch iframe
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='glossIframe']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
#scrape iframe data
for td in soup.find_all("td", class_="tlTD"):
    print(td.find("p").getText())
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea that the selenium code was the problem. Do you mind explaining why I needed to use element_to_be_clickable instead of find_element_by_id?

Comment: The answer is using WebDriverWait with element_to_be_clickable so that it waits to click on the element until the element is ready to be clicked on...but that's sort of the extra sauce here.  the meat of the solution is the switch to the iframe that is presented after the click on source_button. at that point the driver is looking at the source of interest.

Comment: @Breaks Software, I know it sounds like a silly question, but the reason I asked is because I've used the same "find_element_by_id" approach to scrape another iframe on that link and it scraped just fine without having to explicitly switch to the iframe using webdriver. I guess it's just standard practice when scraping an iframe to first check that the element is clickable and then switch into it?

Comment: Yes, it is best practice is to use some flavor of "wait" before taking an action on an element when dealing with dynamic web pages.  This makes the script far more robust.  webdriver cannot take any action inside an iframe unless you've 'switch'ed to that iframe, so I can't explain how your previous experience might have worked.  most likely there was an element with the given id in the 'current' iframe.